# Albumentations RandomCrop with mask different size as image

Tags: python, pytorch, albumentations

is it possible to RandomCrop an image with the size 256x256 and the mask with the size 100x100?

Or RandomGridShuffle and RandomSizedCrop?

https://albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/augmentations.html

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not supported.

The application of RandomCrop or RandomGridShuffle can lead to very strange corner cases.

It is just easier to resize the mask and image to the same size and resize it back when needed.

Two extra lines of code, but you will not get unexpected bugs.